# UWP Background Task System Shutdown

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm learning Win 10 UWP and my goal is to write an SQLite database entry every 15 minutes using a background task.

My question is, what happens to the background task when the user shuts down the system and restarts it later on?

As I can understand, the user has to start the application again manually to register the background task again. Or is the background task somehow registered somewhere and restarts when the system is back up again without having to manually restart the background task again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you've registered your background task, it stays around even after the computer reboots. The user doesn't have to launch your application again.

Comment: That's the answer I needed! How the system manages the background tasks during restarts or shutdowns is not in the scope of UWP itself I presume?

Comment: What happens when the computer reboots, will the system launch the background task as soon as the system reboots or will the system launch the background task at an expected Scheduled time?

Comment: Is this true for out-of-process background task only?

Comment: The background task i created is working while the app is suspended when debugging using Visual Studio lifecycle event manager. But, when i shutdown the app, the background process will also stop.